# how can we get a word in "double quotes using shell script

Tags: shell, substring

H have a sentence leg:  - Hai "how are you" . from this sentence i need to get the words in double quotes in a variable.... 
that means how are you should be in the variable
how can this done in shell script

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
 echo " Hai \"how are you\" " | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with grep to save the needed text in variable (`x` for example)

```
kent$  x=$(echo 'Hai "how are you"'|grep -Po '"\K[^"]+')  
kent$  echo $x
how are you
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use slash "\" for adding quotes with your string.!